# UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent within a modalViewController

Tags: iphone

I am trying to copy the UIImagePickerController as best as I can. If I do that in a regular UITableViewController it shows the StatusBar translucent and you can see the content behind it (just like in apples UIImagePickerController).

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

But if I present a new UIViewController (with a UINavigationController as a subview) as a modalViewController:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myImagePickerController animated:YES];
```

then the StatusBar becomes opaque, it still has this dark grey color but you can't see anything behind it. And yes I have wantsFullScreenLayout, etc. in myImagePickerController viewDidLoad() method.

How do I fix this so It behaves like apples UIImagePickerController, a modalView with translucent StatusBar?

Comment: You can find the source code on http://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController

Answer (score -1):

Try presenting it from the window.

Comment: How do you mean? I have to present it with presentModalViewController: otherwise it'll not behave like apples UIImagePickerController.

Comment: that is what presentModalViewController is kind of doing under the hood.